# Return distance between two locations in SQL Server 2008 using latitude and longitude

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, location

We have a table with places and their latitudes and longitudes.

We are trying to create a function in SQL Server 2008 to list places within next 25 kilometers using a specific latitude and longitude as centre point.

I was wandering if this is a good way to start and test our function and getting current distance between a centre point (current location) and a target location (@latitude/@longitude):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDistanceFromLocation]
(   
    @myCurrentLatitude float,
    @myCurrentLongitude float,
    @latitude float,
    @longitude float
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @radiusOfTheEarth int 
    SET @radiusOfTheEarth = 6371--km

    DECLARE @distance int
    SELECT @distance = ( @radiusOfTheEarth 
        * acos( cos( radians(@myCurrentLatitude) ) 
        * cos( radians( @latitude ) ) 
        * cos( radians( @longitude ) - radians(@myCurrentLongitude) ) + sin( radians(@myCurrentLatitude) ) 
        * sin( radians( @latitude ) ) ) )

    RETURN @distance

END
```

Is it correct or we are missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [great-circle distance](http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-calculation.asp) formula, which is probably accurate enough for you, although you'll have to be the judge of that.

If you want to check the results of your formula, you can use the [geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) data type:

```
declare @geo1 geography = geography::Point(@lat1, @long1, 4326),
        @geo2 geography = geography::Point(@lat2, @long2, 4326)

select @geo1.STDistance(@geo2)
```

and since you are doing a [proximity search](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-2008-proximity-search-with-th), you may want to investigate the `geography` data type further.

Comment: What is 4326? I tried to see MSDN but doesn't have any information about it.

Comment: 4326 is the Spatial Reference ID for the World Geodetic reference system.  For more information see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS84

Answer (score 0):

Would this be valid?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDistanceFromLocation]
(   
    @CurrentLatitude float,
    @CurrentLongitude float,
    @latitude float,
    @longitude float
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @geo1 geography = geography::Point(@lat1, @long1, 4268), 
            @geo2 geography = geography::Point(@lat2, @long2, 4268)

    DECLARE @distance int
    SELECT @distance = @geo1.STDistance(@geo2) 

    RETURN @distance

END
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I'm flagging this post for deletion.